# Mathematical equation in reportlab

Tags: python, reportlab

I use reportlab to create measurement reports of a machine (basically).

At some point, I need to print a few mathematical equations, and some "mathematical formatted text" (see first image as example).

[image]

Is it possible to do something like that in reportlab ? At the moment, I just print "U max", "U min", "R max", but it definitely be better if I was able to format the text in this way.

I didn't find anything in the reportlab documentation (I especially looked in the "Fonts and encoding" and the "Graphics" sections).

Researches on Internet only led me to sorts of outdated posts, where I found that something called "MathTran" [existed](http://two.pairlist.net/pipermail/reportlab-users/2007-July/006154.html) at some point, but now the the website is a [game slots](http://www.mathtran.org) website.

I you have any idea, or know anything, I thank you in advance :).

And have a nice day.

Comment: You just want to use subscripts? Then see [this](https://docs.reportlab.com/rml/userguide/Chapter_7_Advanced_text/).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks a lot ! Sorry that I couldn't name it properly >.<